# How to pass arguments to overridden functions with different interface?

Tags: python, overriding, abstract-class

The situation is: An abstract base class defines a set of common actions, while leaving a bunch of specialized actions to subclasses.

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod
class Common(ABC):
    def __init__(self,ord_obj):
        self.ord_obj = ord_obj
        self.abs_obj = self.generate_abs_obj(?)

    @abstractmethod
    def generate_abs_obj(self):
        # Will be implemented in subclasses
        pass

    def common_operation(self):
        return self.ord_obj + self.abs_obj


class specialize_1(Common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def generate_abs_obj(self,param_1):
        # do something
        return 25

class specialize_2(Common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def generate_abs_obj(self,param_1,param_2):
        # do something
        return param_1+param_2
```

As shown above, `abs_obj` is an object generated by an abstract method and initialized in base class `__init__`. It will be used in the base class by an ordinary method. However, the `generate_abs_obj` in subclasses have different interfaces. How do I call `super().__init__()` with different parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The overall approach that you are using seems to be entirely not-pythonic.  I highly recommend watching Raymond Hettinger explain Super and Pythonic inheritance in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo&t=0s&index=3&list=PLRVdut2KPAguz3xcd22i_o_onnmDKj3MA)